# Visualizing modified SIR model

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, eon

I tried to modify the SIR model from the eon package and did some changes to it. It has a new vaccination parameter attached to it with new parameters beta and omega and Vl and my code is-

```
def test_transmission(u, v, p):

return random.random()<p


def discrete_SIR(G,
            initial_infecteds,beta,
            w,Vl,return_full_data=True):

if G.has_node(initial_infecteds):
    initial_infecteds=[initial_infecteds]           

if return_full_data:
    node_history = defaultdict(lambda : ([tmin], ['S']))
    transmissions = []
    for node in initial_infecteds:
        node_history[node] = ([tmin], ['I'])
        transmissions.append((tmin-1, None, node))



node_history = defaultdict(lambda : ([tmin], ['S']))
#    transmissions = []
for node in initial_infecteds:
    node_history[node] = ([tmin], ['I'])
    #transmissions.append((tmin-1, None, node))


N=G.order()
t = [tmin]
S = [N-len(initial_infecteds)]
I = [len(initial_infecteds)]
R = [0]
V = [0]

susceptible = defaultdict(lambda: True)  
#above line is equivalent to u.susceptible=True for all nodes.

for u in initial_infecteds:
    susceptible[u] = False


infecteds = set(initial_infecteds)

while infecteds and t[-1]<tmax :
    new_infecteds = set()
    vaccinated= set()
    infector = {}  #used for returning full data.  a waste of time otherwise
    for u in infecteds:
     #   print('u-->' +str(u))
        for v in G.neighbors(u):
     #       print('v --> '+ str(v))
        ##vaccination
            if len(vaccinated)+V[-1]< (Vl*N)  : #check if vaccination over or not
                #print(len(vaccinated),Vl*N)
                #print("HI")

                if susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u, v, w): 
                    vaccinated.add(v)
                    susceptible[v] = False
     #               print('transmitting vaccination')

                elif susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u,v,beta):
                    new_infecteds.add(v)
                    susceptible[v]=False
                    infector[v] = [u]
     #               print('transmitting infection')
            else:

    #            print("BYE")
                if susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u, v,beta): 
                    new_infecteds.add(v)
                    susceptible[v] = False
                    infector[v] = [u]

           #infector[v] = [u]


    if return_full_data:
        for v in infector.keys():
            transmissions.append((t[-1], random.choice(infector[v]), v))
        next_time = t[-1]+1
        if next_time <= tmax:
            for u in infecteds:
                node_history[u][0].append(next_time)
                node_history[u][1].append('R')
            for v in new_infecteds:
                node_history[v][0].append(next_time)
                node_history[v][1].append('I')



    infecteds = new_infecteds

    R.append(R[-1]+I[-1])
    V.append(len(vaccinated)+V[-1])
    I.append(len(infecteds))
    S.append(N-V[-1]-I[-1]-R[-1])
    #S.append(S[-1]-V[-1]-I[-1])
    t.append(t[-1]+1)


print(str(R[-1])+','+str(V[-1])+','+str(I[-1])+','+str(S[-1]))  

if not return_full_data:
    return scipy.array(t), scipy.array(S), scipy.array(I), \
           scipy.array(R)
else:
    return EoN.Simulation_Investigation(G, node_history, transmissions)
```

Now I want to run the visualizations on it like in the packagae EON-

```
m=5

G=nx.grid_2d_graph(m,m,periodic=True)
initial_infections = [(u,v) for (u,v) in G if u==int(m/2) and v==int(m/2)]
sim = EoN.basic_discrete_SIR(G,0.5,initial_infecteds = initial_infections,
               return_full_data=True, tmax = 25)

pos = {node:node for node in G}
sim.set_pos(pos)
sim.display(0, node_size = 40) #display time 6
plt.show()
plt.savefig('SIR_2dgrid.png')
```

What changes do I need to do in my code so that the display function works or do I need to make changes in the display function also?

Comment: At present you would need to do modifications to both your code and the display function.  I'm hoping to do the modifications soon so that this is possible without you having to do significant changes.  I'll try to give an answer later (no time at the moment) giving more detail.

Comment: @Joel i did some changes in my code and it seems the simulations are correct but of course its only displaying SIR graphs instead of SIRV. Ill post my changes and if you could tell me what changes to make to display function to include the V parameter that would be helpful

Comment: @Joel did you have time to look into it?..Also you could tell m what needs to be done..I would be happy to contribute to EON.

Comment: Hey - sorry I haven't had a chance to do it.  The first change needed is that when a node becomes `'V'`, you need to update `node_history` for that node.  The second change is that the `__init__` code for the class `Simulation_Investigation(G, node_history, transmissions)` needs to be modified to handle whether the node is `'V'` in the same way it handles S, I, and R.  Finally the `_plot_` method will need to be modified.  I'm hoping to make the code I've written more general so that people can do this with any new status, but I won't have time for a while.

Comment: @Joel ill try to do that and post it here or github for you to look at.

Comment: Actually - I'm very close to having this done now.  Have spent today on it.  I came just now to let you know.  Hope you see this before spending too much effort.

Comment: @Joel thank you...i just started changing the node_history..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the output I now get:[image]

You'll have to install EoN version `1.0.8rc3` or later, which is available on the github page (see [installation instructions](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GettingStarted.html)).  At present `pip` will not work to install it.  I want to make sure I haven't broken anything before I make it the default installed by `pip`.

Here's the code based on yours.  You should look through the changes I've made.  It's also worth looking at [the examples I've put in the documentation](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#visualization) (including an SIRV model where the vaccination rule is different than what you've got).

```
from collections import defaultdict
import EoN
import networkx as nx
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_transmission(u, v, p):
    return random.random()<p


def discrete_SIRV(G, initial_infecteds,beta,
            w,Vl,tmin=0,tmax=float('Inf'), return_full_data=True):

    if G.has_node(initial_infecteds):
        initial_infecteds=[initial_infecteds]           

    if return_full_data:
        node_history = defaultdict(lambda : ([tmin], ['S']))
        transmissions = []
        for node in initial_infecteds:
            node_history[node] = ([tmin], ['I'])
            transmissions.append((tmin-1, None, node))



    '''
    node_history = defaultdict(lambda : ([tmin], ['S']))
    #    transmissions = []
    for node in initial_infecteds:
        node_history[node] = ([tmin], ['I'])
    #transmissions.append((tmin-1, None, node))
    '''

    N=G.order()
    t = [tmin]
    S = [N-len(initial_infecteds)]
    I = [len(initial_infecteds)]
    R = [0]
    V = [0]

    susceptible = defaultdict(lambda: True)  
    #above line is equivalent to u.susceptible=True for all nodes.

    for u in initial_infecteds:
        susceptible[u] = False


    infecteds = set(initial_infecteds)

    while infecteds and t[-1]<tmax :
        new_infecteds = set()
        vaccinated= set()
        infector = {}  #used for returning full data.  a waste of time otherwise
        for u in infecteds:
            #   print('u-->' +str(u))
            for v in G.neighbors(u):
                #       print('v --> '+ str(v))
                ##vaccination
                if len(vaccinated)+V[-1]< (Vl*N)  : #check if vaccination over or not
                    #print(len(vaccinated),Vl*N)
                    #print("HI")

                    if susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u, v, w): 
                        vaccinated.add(v)
                        susceptible[v] = False

                        '''It's probably better to define a `new_vaccinated`
                        set and then do the `return_full_data` stuff later
                        where all the others are done.'''
                        if return_full_data:
                            node_history[v][0].append(t[-1]+1)
                            node_history[v][1].append('V')
     #               print('transmitting vaccination')

                    elif susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u,v,beta):
                        new_infecteds.add(v)
                        susceptible[v]=False
                        infector[v] = [u]
                        #               print('transmitting infection')
                else:

                    #            print("BYE")
                    if susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u, v,beta): 
                        new_infecteds.add(v)
                        susceptible[v] = False
                        infector[v] = [u]

                        #infector[v] = [u]


        if return_full_data:
            for v in infector.keys():
                '''This random choice is no longer needed as you've taken out 
                the possibility of multiple nodes transmitting to `v` in a given
                time step.  Now only the first one encountered does it.'''

                transmissions.append((t[-1], random.choice(infector[v]), v))
            next_time = t[-1]+1
            if next_time <= tmax:
                for u in infecteds:
                    node_history[u][0].append(next_time)
                    node_history[u][1].append('R')
                for v in new_infecteds:
                    node_history[v][0].append(next_time)
                    node_history[v][1].append('I')



        infecteds = new_infecteds

        R.append(R[-1]+I[-1])
        V.append(len(vaccinated)+V[-1])
        I.append(len(infecteds))
        S.append(N-V[-1]-I[-1]-R[-1])
        #S.append(S[-1]-V[-1]-I[-1])
        t.append(t[-1]+1)


        print(str(R[-1])+','+str(V[-1])+','+str(I[-1])+','+str(S[-1]))  

    if not return_full_data:
        return scipy.array(t), scipy.array(S), scipy.array(I), \
           scipy.array(R)
    else:
        return EoN.Simulation_Investigation(G, node_history, transmissions, possible_statuses=['S', 'I', 'R', 'V'])



print(EoN.__version__)
print("line above needs to be 1.0.8rc3 or greater or it will not work\n\n")

m=20

G=nx.grid_2d_graph(m,m,periodic=True)
initial_infections = [(u,v) for (u,v) in G if u==int(m/2) and v==int(m/2)]
beta=0.8
Vl=0.3
w=0.1

sim = discrete_SIRV(G, initial_infections, beta, w, Vl, return_full_data=True)

pos = {node:node for node in G}
sim.set_pos(pos)
sim.sim_update_colordict({'S': '#009a80','I':'#ff2000', 'R':'gray','V': '#5AB3E6'})
sim.display(6, node_size = 40) #display time 6
plt.savefig('SIRV_2dgrid.png')
```